# Text in Label showing up as odd symbols - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm sure this question has been asked before, or is obvious, but I'm struggling to find anything from a google search.

I just opened up a winform application on a different machine (my old one is being replaced) and one of the labels on the Splash Screen is showing as this:

[image]

This should instead say: "Application Manager".

I'm really not sure why letters are being replaced with odd symbols. Can someone point me in the right direction, or let me know why this is happening?

I am using Remote desktop connection (and I believe I had the Splash Screen set to double buffered) which may be causing the problem. However ever when I remove the text and try typing it in again, it shows up as symbols.

EDIT: So changing the font to something different, then changing it back, seemed to fix it. However an explanation of why this happened would be good.

Comment: I don't know why it happened, but these symbols belong to the "Wingdings"-font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the Control or the Form is set to the use WingDings Font.

Comment: Thanks. It was set to Sans Serif. I changed to Calibri, then back again, and it works now. No idea why it was showing up has WingDings! Something to do with Remote Desktop connection perhaps?